# Regex matching with exclusions

Tags: regex, sublimetext3, regex-negation

I am working on creating a custom markup syntax and trying to match certain strings surround by special characters. For example `//Some text//` is matched fine with regex `\/\/`.

The expression `\/\/` works in most cases, except when there are urls in the text and throw everything off. How can I exclude/handle cases when there is `p:` or `s:` preceding the double slash, like in urls:

> http:// or https://

I was thinking to exclude `p://` and `s://` but not sure how.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: Not sure, using Sublime Text 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind regex:

```
(?<!https:|http:)//.*?//
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEYf6i/4)

`(?<!https:|http:)` is negative lookbehind assertion that will fail if we have `https:` or `http:` before `//`